# Tricky table formatting in css

Tags: html, css, html-table, css-tables

I have a table with two levels of headers, the first level having different colspans, and I would like it to look like the below image.

I can center the text in the first level of headers but I can't manage to do the borders the way I want it.

The HTML code is generated server-side so I would like to do all formatting in a CSS file.

Any help would be appreciated.

[image: the table]

[jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/7fD3a/)

HTML Code below:

```
    <table>
<tr>
    <th align=left></th>
    <th text-align=center colspan=5>Account</th>
    <th text-align=center colspan=1>Global</th>
    <th text-align=center colspan=3>Office</th>
    <th text-align=center colspan=13>Strategy</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th align=left></th>
    <th>AGRMF</th>
    <th>AIEMF</th>
    <th>AISAR</th>
    <th>ALPHA</th>
    <th>SGAM</th>
    <th>Global</th>
    <th>ASIA</th>
    <th>COMBINED</th>
    <th>NY</th>
    <th>ACA</th>
    <th>AJ</th>
    <th>AM</th>
    <th>ARGO</th>
    <th>AV</th>
    <th>AY</th>
    <th>EMFI</th>
    <th>EVNT</th>
    <th>GDM</th>
    <th>GXM</th>
    <th>LMT</th>
    <th>QUAD</th>
    <th>XMV</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th align=left>BalanceSheetLeverage</th>
    <td align=center>content</td>
    <td align=center>content</td>
    <td align=center>content</td>
    <td align=center>content</td>
    <td align=center>content</td>
    <td align=center>content</td>
    <td align=center>content</td>
    <td align=center>content</td>
    <td align=center>content</td>
    <td align=center>content</td>
    <td align=center>content</td>
    <td align=center>content</td>
    <td align=center>content</td>
    <td align=center>content</td>
    <td align=center>content</td>
    <td align=center>content</td>
    <td align=center>content</td>
    <td align=center>content</td>
    <td align=center>content</td>
    <td align=center>content</td>
    <td align=center>content</td>
    <td align=center>content</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th align=left>CounterpartyRisk</th>
    <td align=center>content</td>
    <td align=center>content</td>
    <td align=center>content</td>
    <td align=center>content</td>
    <td align=center>content</td>
    <td align=center>content</td>
    <td align=center>content</td>
    <td align=center>content</td>
    <td align=center>content</td>
    <td align=center>content</td>
    <td align=center>content</td>
    <td align=center>content</td>
    <td align=center>content</td>
    <td align=center>content</td>
    <td align=center>content</td>
    <td align=center>content</td>
    <td align=center>content</td>
    <td align=center>content</td>
    <td align=center>content</td>
    <td align=center>content</td>
    <td align=center>content</td>
    <td align=center>content</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: are you on `html-table` or `css-table`...?? it certainly can't be both!!!...please show your code too!!

Comment: Provide code of your html, at least ,please

Comment: Can you please add a jsfiddle of your current version of the code?

Comment: at the moment it's pure HTML with only a `text-align:center` in the first `<th>...</th>` line
The table showed is the result I would want. At the moment I can't get the borders.

Comment: Please post your code on JSFiddle.net

Comment: like this? : http://jsfiddle.net/crazytonyi/7fD3a/2/

Comment: yes something along those lines. I have validated another answer which does the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fQvLv/1/

**CSS**

```
.level-one-left{
    border:2px solid #000; 
    border-right:1px solid #000;
}
.level-one-right{
    border:2px solid #000; 
    border-left:1px solid #000;
}
.level-two-left{
    border:2px solid #000; 
    border-right:1px solid #000;
    border-top:0px;

}
.level-two-right{
    border:2px solid #000; 
    border-left:1px solid #000;
    border-top:0px;
}
.left-side{
    border-left:2px solid #000;  
}
.right{
    border-right:2px solid #000;
}
.top{
    border-top:2px solid #000;
}
.bottom{
    border-bottom:2px solid #000;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<table cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td style="border:0"></td>
        <th class="level-one-left" colspan="5">Level One</th>
        <th class="level-one-right" colspan="3">Level One</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <th class="level-two-left" colspan="5">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>Level Two</th>
                    <th>Level Two</th>
                    <th>Level Two</th>
                    <th>Level Two</th>
                    <th>Level Two</th>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </th>
        <th class="level-two-right" colspan="3">
        <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>Level Two</th>
                    <th>Level Two</th>
                    <th>Level Two</th>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th class="left-side top right">Test One</th>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td class="right">Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td class="right">Content</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <th class="left-side right">Test Two</th>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td class="right">Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td class="right">Content</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <th class="left-side right">Test Three</th>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td class="right">Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td class="right">Content</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <th class="left-side right">Test Four</th>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td class="right">Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td class="right">Content</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <th class="left-side right bottom">Test Five</th>
        <td class="bottom">Content</td>
        <td class="bottom">Content</td>
        <td class="bottom">Content</td>
        <td class="bottom">Content</td>
        <td class="bottom right">Content</td>
        <td class="bottom">Content</td>
        <td class="bottom">Content</td>
        <td class="bottom right">Content</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

It's a longer way but it should get you started..

Comment: Unfortunately no. The important things are the borders and to use CSS only (with probably the creation of one or two classes)

Comment: Ok, I will add borders that is not a big deal :) give me few min

Comment: Thanks. I'll have to create classes server side for it to work though.

Comment: @Chapo, you are welcome I know its not 100% like the image but its close enough so you can figure it out. I just don't have any more time to do it..

Answer (score 1):

is `css-border` you priority??

<kbd>[**working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/7fD3a/1/)</kbd>

**css**

```
table,tr,th,td{
    border:1px solid black; /*<-- define borders */
    border-spacing: 0px; /*<-- cellspacing */
    border-collapse: separate;/*<-- cellpadding */
}
```

**EDIT**

[**no classes needed in this demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/7fD3a/3/)

Just add this in your css and you will be fine without making classes and have the same HTML markup!!

```
table{
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th,td{
    border:1px solid black;
    border-spacing: 0px;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

table tr:nth-child(1) th:nth-child(1)
{
    border:none;
}
table tr:nth-child(2) th:nth-child(1)
{
    border:none;
}
```

**EDIT 2**

<kbd>[**final work**](http://jsfiddle.net/7fD3a/4/)</kbd>

```
 ___^^___ this contains your exact markup as per pic!!
```

Comment: Yes it is. You didn't match the image given as example though. I do not want borders everywhere that is the tricky part.

Comment: @Chapo : though you have accepted answer....please check my edited answer....you wont need to make separate classes in the css after it!! :)

Comment: @Chapo : i love a feedback..please provide one too!! :)

Comment: I like yours its clean however it doesn't match the picture. At least not the jsFiddle file you have provided.

Comment: @Ljubisa : i didn't touched you html as you said => `The HTML code is generated server-side so I would like to do all formatting in a CSS file.`....but i believe, having this css,playing with HTML table isn't a big deal...want me to amend your table too!!???